# How to add Google calender events directly from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

I am trying to add a script that syncs data from a Google sheet directly to my calendar. I  used the following script that partially works:

```
    function createAllDayEvent() {
      let liveRS = 
    CalendarApp.getCalendarById("tn6mupl*************pekhk@group.calendar.google.com");
      let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

      let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      schedule.splice(0, 15);

      schedule.forEach(function (entry) {
        liveRS.createEvent(entry[20], entry[1], entry[1]);
      });
    }
```

My two main issues are that the calendar now adds an event when there is a blank cell in the sheet, and the calendar also seems to continually add events rather than just once.

How do I fix these?

Comment: Which cell"  Your are looping through each row which means there is data in at least one cell of that row.

Comment: clean your data, use filter function to get rid of these blank cell you don't need.   in forEach function , it will go through length of the values times , if schedule length == 10, it will call can create event 10 times.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Are you able to give a little more detail? I do not want to get rid of all blank cells in the sheet as other people have events on those days. I cannot see where I have included schedule length or how/where I can change that? Thank you again!